# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE envrinment variable to

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxx.xx.xx.xx.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        }
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'

```
compile files('libs/DTBSCommon.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.0.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.0.6'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.6'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to your build tool version and compileSDKVersion.

Here is a workarond for it.

First of all download and install all available updates from SDK Manager.
Then create a new project. As you are using google play services plugin in your current app, apply google play services plugin to newly created project.

Now Compare the build.gradle(Module App) for both the applications and make changes to in your old project build.gradle(module app). Also update the various dependencies to their latest versions. After making changes sync the gradle and it should work like charm.

Comment: For your reference some latest versions are:
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

Comment: compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
  compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'